# Why are comments pointing out critical errors in questions getting removed?

Tags: discussion

The second paragraph in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1272440/163253 is patently false. I down voted the answer, up voted a few answer that weren't wrong and commented about the problem. The original answerer came back and decided to argue the point (for which clear counter-points were given) and the result is that all the comments were marked as extended discussion and the criticism was removed. This seems to lead to an unhealthy system whereby posters need only run the comments off the rails in order to remove any comments pointing out how their answer is wrong.

My question: Is it the policy of superuser to remove critical comments when other unrelated discussions get added?

Comment: It takes two to tango. Make your point and [move on](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: You don't seem to follow. He wasn't engaging me, he was engaging 5 other people. Some of which were making completely invalid points. I'm simply suggesting that this guy rambling on about other stuff shouldn't get my criticism removed. Nothing I can do if he wants to get into it with other people.

Comment: The content was not removed. It is normal when there are a large number of comments on a question or answer to [move them to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69519/discussion-on-answer-by-eugen-rieck-how-many-bits-per-digit-in-the-decimal-syste)

Comment: @DavidPostill For all intents and purposes that is removed. Other than the first sentence, that answer is completely wrong and misleading. I'd flag it as being a terrible answer but I've been told that the appropriate action is to simply down-vote and point out the problem (in this case a statement roughly equivalent to suggesting 2+2=6 because 2 and 6 are both even). I guess I'll make an edit to it to fix the problems, though I think that's unfair to gronostaj who actually bother to spend the time drafting a quality answer.